# Bazel builds cause issues when I install TensorFlow using pip

Tags: tensorflow, build, bazel

So the documentation mentions that it is better to install from source, then build a pip package. Why is this recommended over doing a direct pip install using the wheel file provided on the downloads page? [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation)

I tried the direct pip install and then runnning some scripts in the inception folder.This results in errors with bazel not finding some of the dependencies. I am guessing this is related to not building tensorflow from source, but I can't figure out why this is the case. Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: What error messages are you getting using bazel?

Answer (score 0):

Installing from pip is supported, can you provide more details on your os and the specific errors you saw?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to build from source is simply performance.

**Building and installing from source**

*The default TensorFlow binaries target the broadest range of hardware to make TensorFlow accessible to everyone. If using CPUs for training or inference, it is recommended to compile TensorFlow with all of the optimizations available for the CPU in use. Speedups for training and inference on CPU are documented below in Comparing compiler optimizations.
To install the most optimized version of TensorFlow, build and install from source. If there is a need to build TensorFlow on a platform that has different hardware than the target, then cross-compile with the highest optimizations for the target platform. The following command is an example of using bazel to compile for a specific platform*

ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide